# Always empty multipart-encoded files in second POST

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to send a file in two different websites via POST. So, I use Requests library.

The photos in the second response is always have zero size. Even when I change web-site order.

```
import requests

data = {'id': 1}

f = open('/tmp/photo7.jpg', 'rb')
image = {'image': ('photo7.jpg', f)}

# works fine
requests.post('http://site.com/', data=data, files=image)
# empty file
requests.post('http://othersite.com/', data=data, files=image)
```

What could be the problem?

I think that the problem in the file object’s current position in the file (possible, it's in the end of the file after the first response), but I'm not sure.

I can't made seek(0) properly, traceback: http://pastebin.com/gnD2c1AR

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `seek` is the right way, but you pass the *result* of seek (which will be 0) instead of the filehandle to `requests.post` in this line:

```
files = {'image': ('photo7.jpg', f.seek(0))}
```

Try this:

```
...
requests.post('http://site.com/', data=data, files=image)
f.seek(0)
requests.post('http://othersite.com/', data=data, files=image)
```